# How to echo one out of many variables from function

Tags: php, html, function, variables, echo

I think this is a very easy one, but I have been struggling on this issue for quite some time now.. 
Here is an example of my situation:

I have a function with multiple variables in an external file called functions.php, these variables are values from database, but as an example:

```
function someVariables(){
    $var1 = 'First variable';
    $var2 = 'Second variable';
    $var3 = 'Third variable';
}
```

The file gets imported at the top of the index page

```
<?php import('functions.php')?>
```

Somewhere in the index.php I want to echo $var2, but nothing shows, just a blank spot.

```
<h1><?php echo someVariables($var1);?></h1>
<p>some random text</p>
<h2><?php echo someVariables($var2);?></h2>
<p>some random text</p>
<h3><?php echo someVariables($var3);?></h3>
<p>some random text</p>
```

How can I echo these variables one by one on different places?
These variables should be shown across the page in multiple divs & tags...
If I echo one variable inside the function and do this:

```
<h1> <?php someVariables();?> </h1>
```

it works with the one variable echo, so there is nothing wrong with the variables.

Comment: why not return an array from the function???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, maintain the variables as an array inside the function `someVariables()` and return a specific variable value based on the function call, like this:

```
function someVariables($var){
    $array = array('var1' => 'First variable', 'var2' => 'Second variable', 'var3' => 'Third variable');
    return $array[$var];
}
```

Subsequently, you can call this function with appropriate variable name like this:

```
<h1><?php echo someVariables('var1'); ?></h1>
<p>some random text</p>
<h2><?php echo someVariables('var2'); ?></h2>
<p>some random text</p>
<h3><?php echo someVariables('var3'); ?></h3>
<p>some random text</p>
```